# Loading Spring context using blueprint and exporting a spring bean reference

Tags: spring, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi, aries

Am a newbie to OSGI. Our company has decided to use Fuse ESB as our deployment container and  blueprint as the IOC. The problem I face is that we have a bunch of spring applications in various spring technologies , for brevity, let us consider spring batch. We have been used to the spring batch dsl and its way of working. Is there a way I could use the same spring application and load it via blueprint (Aries blueprint by the way not Gemini) And also refer to a spring bean and export it via blueprint? Is that a blatant 'no' or even if possible, something we should not be attempting at all considering one IoC container inside another being a very bad practice? Or if someone has attempted, found succes and if its doable, some pointers on doing it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say spring batch dsl, do you mean spring xml namespace. Eg its xml tags in a spring xml file? If so I think that namespace handler from spring batch *only* support Spring, and therefore you cannot use that namespace dsl in a blueprint xml file.

For this to work then Spring Batch project would need to offer a Blueprint XML DSL also. eg this is what we do for Apache Camel, offering both a Spring XML and Blueprint XML for the Camel DSL.

With Fuse ESB you can also use Spring XML. So instead of using Blueprint, you can still use Spring XML (its using spring-dm under the covers in the OSGi container). So this would allow you to use the Spring Batch XML DSL.